# Sql server - Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert records into a table and need to insert the the column SubscriberWeightingID that should be sequential order in an existing table ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting in Sql sever database. Ideally the SubscriberWeightingID should be latest based on that table and should continue in sequential order for the remaining. This is what I tried but getting error
How do i achieve that
I have used the orber by clause but it is still complaining. Is there another way to do it. I have basically 50 such inserts to execute

```
insert into ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting ([SubscriberWeightingID],[SubscriberNK],[WeightingAmount],[IsActive]) values ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [SubscriberWeightingID]),'NSFR80R0040C0090','0',1)   
insert into ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting ([SubscriberWeightingID],[SubscriberNK],[WeightingAmount],[IsActive]) values ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [SubscriberWeightingID]),'NSFR80R0040C0100','0',1)   
insert into ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting ([SubscriberWeightingID],[SubscriberNK],[WeightingAmount],[IsActive]) values ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [SubscriberWeightingID]),'NSFR80R0040C0110','0',1)
```

Error

```
Invalid column name 'SubscriberWeightingID'.
Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want to do, but maybe instead of using `ROW_NUMBER()`, try using `SELECT MAX(SubscriberWeightingID) + 1 FROM ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting`... That is if you don't have it set to auto increment.

Comment: Unfortunately the auto increment feature of that table is not set to automatic. Hence when new records are inserted , it should insert based on what was the last Id + 1

Comment: How would i add SELECT MAX(SubscriberWeightingID) + 1 in the values statement

Comment: Modify the table so it uses an `IDENTITY` column or a `DEFAULT` constraint with a `SEQUENCE` and let the server generate it for you. Using the proposed `SELECT MAX()` is vulnerable to race conditions and may generate duplicate values for concurrent inserts.

Comment: Instead of values, use: `SELECT MAX(SubscriberWeightingID) + 1,'NSFR80R0040C0090','0',1 FROM ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually increment an id, you can use:

```
insert into ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting ([SubscriberWeightingID],[SubscriberNK],[WeightingAmount],[IsActive]) 
    select coalesce(max(SubscriberWeightingID) + 1, 1), 'NSFR80R0040C0090', '0', 1) 
    from ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting;
```

This mechanism is *highly* NOT recommended, because it is not thread-safe.  Different `insert`s can insert the same value.

However, if you are stuck in a situation where you have a table with no `identity` column and no column defaulted to a sequence, then this is one way to do what you want.  It should only be used until you fix the database to automatically generate the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use identity column to achieve that. However if you want to achieve that as you tried in your code then please try this:

```
insert into ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting ([SubscriberWeightingID],[SubscriberNK],[WeightingAmount],[IsActive]) 
values ((select isnull(max([SubscriberWeightingID]),0)+1 
from ALO_DimSubscriberWeighting),'NSFR80R0040C0090','0',1)
```